# Change site address http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to something like http://www.rajSite.com in Django

Tags: python, django, django-3.1

I have tried python manage.py runserver [www.rajSites.com](http://www.rajSites.com) but didnt work
I searched in google for more than 1 hr. No info is available.
I am using the development server that comes with Django.
How to change https://127.0.0.1 to https://rajSites.com(Own Url)..
Please Share your Ideas regarding this...
Advance Thanks for helping...

Comment: https://127.0.0.1/ is in your local host i.e, it is running on your local machine. To change to www.rajSites.com you have  to push your application into production and get a domain for that

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to test on your local machine add a host entry in your hosts file (Usually `/etc/hosts` on Unix and `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows), for example:

```
0.0.0.0 www.rajsites.com
```

Now if you open `www.rajsites.com` on your computer you'll be accessing your localhost